# Laravel SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE not working for debugging web calls

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm, xdebug, laravel-sail

I have started to play with my first Laravel project on a MacOS. I am using Laravel Sail for running the project inside a container and everything seems to work except the debugging part.

Versions used:

- Laravel 8.66,
- PHP 8.0.12,
- Xdebug 3.1.1

According to [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sail#debugging-with-xdebug) we can set **SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE** to enable the **debug** mode. However, the debugging is not working in PhpStorm even if it is set to listen for incoming connections. I have seen that running `php -i` in container returns different configs for **Xdebug** comparing to what we see in `phpinfo()` from browser even if the Configuration file is the same one.

Here are some screenshots from browser:

[image: WEB - PHP configuration files]
[image: WEB - PHP Xdebug configs]

Here are screenshots from what I see in the command line:

[image: CLI - PHP configuration files]
[image: CLI - PHP Xdebug configs]

As it can be seen in the attached screenshots, in console is used the **XDEBUG_MODE** env var, while in browser is used **xdebug.mode**. Is is possible to have the same configs in console and browser via **SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE** ?

This is the Dockerfile that is used:

```
FROM ubuntu:21.04

LABEL maintainer="Taylor Otwell"

ARG WWWGROUP

WORKDIR /var/www/html

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV TZ=UTC

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y gnupg gosu curl ca-certificates zip unzip git supervisor sqlite3 libcap2-bin libpng-dev python2 \
    && mkdir -p ~/.gnupg \
    && chmod 600 ~/.gnupg \
    && echo "disable-ipv6" >> ~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf \
    && apt-key adv --homedir ~/.gnupg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys E5267A6C \
    && apt-key adv --homedir ~/.gnupg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys C300EE8C \
    && echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu hirsute main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ppa_ondrej_php.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y php8.0-cli php8.0-dev \
       php8.0-pgsql php8.0-sqlite3 php8.0-gd \
       php8.0-curl php8.0-memcached \
       php8.0-imap php8.0-mysql php8.0-mbstring \
       php8.0-xml php8.0-zip php8.0-bcmath php8.0-soap \
       php8.0-intl php8.0-readline php8.0-pcov \
       php8.0-msgpack php8.0-igbinary php8.0-ldap \
       php8.0-redis php8.0-swoole php8.0-xdebug \
    && php -r "readfile('http://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer \
    && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash - \
    && apt-get install -y nodejs \
    && curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - \
    && echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y yarn \
    && apt-get install -y mysql-client \
    && apt-get install -y postgresql-client \
    && apt-get -y autoremove \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

RUN setcap "cap_net_bind_service=+ep" /usr/bin/php8.0

RUN groupadd --force -g $WWWGROUP sail
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash --no-user-group -g $WWWGROUP -u 1337 sail

COPY start-container /usr/local/bin/start-container
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
COPY php.ini /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/99-sail.ini
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/start-container

EXPOSE 8000

ENTRYPOINT ["start-container"]
```

And this is my docker-compose.yml:

```
# For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.0
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.0/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
            PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=my.local"
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
        volumes:
            - 'sailmysql:/var/lib/mysql'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sailmysql:
        driver: local
```

Answer (score 4):

> As it can be seen in the attached screenshots, in console is used the XDEBUG_MODE env var, while in browser is used xdebug.mode.

Xdebug uses `XDEBUG_MODE` if it is set, otherwise it falls back to the value of the `xdebug.mode` setting.

I don't know which web server Sail uses, but some will strip out the environment variables — including `XDEBUG_MODE`.

So you can either fix that, or update the `Dockerfile` to add a line below:

```
COPY php.ini /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/99-sail.ini
```

Which says:

```
COPY xdebug.ini /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/999-xdebug.ini
```

And add to the contents of `xdebug.ini` (in the same directory as `php.ini`):

```
xdebug.mode=develop,debug
```

Comment: Thank you @Derick. This is the second solution that I have tried, The debugger works as expected if configs are added in xdebug.ini, but I am still curios why the approach from Laravel docs with SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE is not working for debugging web calls as I am using only tools provided directly by Laravel.

Comment: I can't help much there, as Laravel Sail is not something I've any influence over. You could perhaps send them a bug report, as I think you're not the only one having this issue with them.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I'm also on macOS.

You must use the `export` command, like this:

```
export SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE=develop,debug
```

Comment: Can this be added in the docker-compose.yml or it needs to be added in Dockerfile or .ini files ?

Comment: @AlexDomsa I just execute this command in Zsh.

Comment: thank you. I know that we can run commands in terminal, but I was wondering why those are not working from docker files.

Answer (score 0):

in ~/.env, add:

```
SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE=debug
```

You can see in the docker-compose file it uses the value of this variable, or `off` by default.

```
XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
```

You'll probably have to restart your docker containers for it to take affect.

Comment: I remember that I have tried this at the time this question was posted, but it was not working as expected. Will need to retry at some pointt

Answer (score 0):

I'm using ***Visual Studio Code*** as my editor and debugger. and other than changing the the value of `SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE` to `develop,debug` in my `.env` file the only other change I had to make to get this working was to update the `launch.json` file to add a path mapping from the path where the code is on the container to where it is on my local hdd.

The config for "Listen for Xdebug" looks like this:

```
   {
      "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
      "type": "php",
      "request": "launch",
      "port": 9003,
      "pathMappings": {
        "/var/www/html": "${workspaceFolder}"
      }
    },
```

I didn't have to make any changes to the docker container config or the Dockerfile itself, I havn't even exported it.

I'm guessing from the tag on the question that OP is using PHPStorm, and they have [instructions on their site for setting the path mapping](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/troubleshooting-php-debugging.html#no-mappings) too.